# How to switch between JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML website which has a very basic HTML structure.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <head>
    <title>Cool Site Bro</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    . . . Script Contents . . .
       Draw elements to pages,
       functions, etc.

  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Which uses JavaScript to draw elements on the page to make a simple graph.

With `divs` or other `html` objects I know you can take advantage of the `css` property display and use **JavaScript** or **jQuery** to change display from block to none or vice versa. Is there anything similar for script tags to hide the contents of one and show another, I feel a page refresh and JavaScript is required.

What would the best way to switch between two scripts on an event like clicking a button?

Comment: if you are trying to switch between scripts on click event of a button, just set the onclick to one function, and in that function set the onclick of that button to the other function and vice versa.

Comment: Hiding a script tag does nothing, you're probably looking for basic [**event handlers**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)

Comment: You should probably start with a general understanding of JS. http://www.lynda.com/JavaScript-training-tutorials/244-0.html?category=beginner_337

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to hide the whole `<script>` tag. You just need to make a part of your code inactive. The way to achive this is to put the part of your JavaScript code inside the function.

Then, you can call one function, or another. So, best way to switch between two scripts on an event like clicking a button would be:

```
<button onclick="function1()" ondblclick="function2()"></button>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the built in [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) functions from jQuery.